# PowerShell - how to open PowerShell as admin and launch script as admin

Tags: powershell, admin, uac, runas, runspace

I am struggling with a very complex problem. Application which my script must install requires elevation of admin rights. Attaching to this application is also available only for an admin.
First of all, I am setting execution policy:

```
try
{
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
  Write-Output "Completed"
}
catch
{
 throw $PSItem
}
```

My next PowerShell script creates a PSCredential object with domain\user combination and password. After that, it uses the following command to open the .exe setup file:

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $credential -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -command &{Start-Process "' + $filePathSetup + '" -wait -verb runas}')
```

and proceeds with executing installation code.

It works when I manually open PowerShell ISE with admin credentials provided and paste my script. However, in practice I am running my scripts from external software (Blue Prism) and I can neither use GUI nor perform manual activities. Application needs to be installed without any human interruption, entirely programmatically, so I cannot open PowerShell as admin on my own.

What am I doing instead? I create a *Runspace* and a *PowerShell* Object, add my script which installs the app to this *PowerShell* Object and invoke it this way:

```
Runspace runspace;

try {

  runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
  if(STA == true) {
    runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
  } else {
    runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.MTA;
  }
  runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.ReuseThread;
  runspace.Open();

} catch(System.Exception ex) {
  ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
  return;
}

//-Create PowerShell----------------------------------------------------
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell PS;

try {

  PS = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
  PS.Runspace = runspace;
  PS.AddScript(PSCode);

} catch(System.Exception ex) {
  runspace.Close();
  ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
  return;
}

//-Add parameters to PowerShell-----------------------------------------
    foreach(DataRow ThisRow in Parameters.Rows) {
        PS.AddParameter(ThisRow["Name"].ToString().Trim(), ThisRow["Value"].ToString().Trim());
  }

//-Invoke PowerShell----------------------------------------------------
try {

  Collection<PSObject> Ret = PS.Invoke();
  runspace.Close();
```

And what is my problem? I cannot switch to admin within this code, but it is required for me to **run both PowerShell & the application as admin** whereas now I am only running the app as admin via PowerShell. I heard of an old *Impersonate* class which would be helpful but it is no longer supported. What would you suggest me to do?

PS **No manual actions please.** I know how to press right mouse button to open contextual menu and select Run as Admin ;)

Comment: If you are asking if you can elevate a process from an unelevated process without causing the UAC prompt, the answer is no, and this is by design. If you are asking how to elevate a program from script (thus causing a UAC prompt), you can use the `runas` verb. I wrote a [free tool](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/elevate/) that can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you, @Bill_Stewart, however this is not my aim. The script should install 2 applications periodically on 28 virtual machines without any human action (including UAC prompt which cannot be automated).

Comment: If your installations require administrator privilege, then the process that starts the installations must already be running elevated.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, it sounds like a vicious circle. Do you think it is possible to "attach" to runspace Object with admin credentials? It would solve this problem of double elevation.

Comment: There's no circle. If your installations require elevation, then the process from which you launch the installations must already be elevated. This is the main reason why software distribution tools use the `SYSTEM` account. If you are asking if you can elevate a non-elevated process automatically without invoking a UAC prompt, the answer is no.

Comment: So the conclusion is that I wrote scripts which are unusable. Unfortunately, applications are so restrictive that installing them without elevating admin credentials is not possible. If without UAC prompt it is not real to elevate a non-elevated process, it means that my workmate needs to install applications on his own 28 times each month which is frustrating but necessary. Thank you for your answers, Bill.

Comment: Again: If you are asking if you can automatically elevate from a non-elevated process without the UAC prompt appearing, then the answer is no. This is by design. (Imagine if this were possible: Malware could automatically elevate itself and install as administrator.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue here is but we do something at startup across all BP machines that requires admin privileges. To do this we set a task in task scheduler to 'run with highest privileges' whether 'user is logged in or not' then that task will fire a cmd script which points to our powershell files and they all run fine without admin prompts. Task scheduler requests the admin credentials on the machine during task config but I think that would solve what you're attempting here.